# Apache Kafka Cleanup while consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Playing around with Apache Kafka and its retention mechanism I'm thinking about following situation:

- A consumer fetches first batch of messages with offsets 1-5
- The cleaner deletes the first 10 messages, so the topic now has offsets 11-15
- In the next poll, the consumer fetches the next batch with offsets 11-15

As you can see the consumer lost the offsets 6-10.

Question, is such a situation possible at all? With other words, will the cleaner execute while there is an active consumer? If yes, is the consumer able to somehow recognize that gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such a scenario can happen. The exact steps will be a bit different:

- Consumer fetches message 1-5
- Messages 1-10 are deleted
- Consumer tries to fetch message 6 but this offset is out of range
- Consumer uses its offset reset policy `auto.offset.reset` to find a new valid offset.

  - If set to `latest`, the consumer moves to the end of the partition
  - If set to `earliest` the consumer moves to offset 11
  - If `none` or unset, the consumer throws an exception

To avoid such scenarios, you should monitor the **lead** of your consumer group. It's similar to the lag, but the lead indicates how far from the start of the partition the consumer is. Being near the start has the risk of messages being deleted before they are consumed.

If consumers are near the limits, you can dynamically add more consumers or increase the topic retention size/time if needed.

Setting `auto.offset.reset` to `none` will throw an exception if this happens, the other values only log it.

Comment: Thanks Mickael! Question answered. The `auto.offset.reset` property with the `none` value is realy what I can make use of.

Answer (score 0):

- Question, is such a situation possible at all? will the cleaner execute while there is an active consumer
  Yes, if the messages have crossed TTL (Time to live) period before they are consumed, this situation is possible.
- Is the consumer able to somehow recognize that gap?
  In case where you suspect your configuration (high consumer lag, low TTL) might lead to this, the consumer should track offsets. kafka-consumer-groups.sh command gives you the information position of all consumers in a consumer group as well as how far behind the end of the log they are.